# How To Use The Grid System Of Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I Am Little Bit Confused In Using The Grid system of Bootstrap. Here I wanted to make 6 divs or containters that use full width in smaller devices like mobiles and they use 25% of the width or i get 4 divs in medium devices like tablets and in the large devices i get 6 divs (in desktop screen)
But here i am facing some issues . Can You help me out!

[image]
i have got all 6 of my divs using full width in large and medium devices which is incorrect i want 6 of them to be displayed in a single row in large device and 4 of them to be displayed in medium devices

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] . Code should never be presented as images.

Comment: [The docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) lay this all out very well. Have another look. Note that Bootstrap has always been "mobile first", so your column classes should be listed small-to-large for the most intuitive reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first specifying the "col" and then your responsive "cols"

like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">Test</div>
</div>
```

I think this will solve your problem (not tested it)